# zend - make a variable global from a routed URL

Tags: zend-framework, routes, global-variables

I'm still experimenting with URL routes and just managed to get it to work.

my routes.ini has this:

> [production]
>   routes.register.route = :lang/register
>   routes.register.defaults.controller = register
>   routes.register.defaults.action = index
>   routes.register.defaults.lang = en
>   routes.register.reqs.lang = "[a-z]{2}"

My URL would look like this:
http://www.mysite.com/en/register
So now, in my controller I can do this:

`$lang =  $request->getParam('lang');`

My problem is: I'm trying to get a list of countries in a select element, which depending if the lang element is english or french, will return the countries in said language.

To do so, I would need to pass "lang" to the form.
Then in the form, pass it to the model querying the countries there.
And if there's a change, it makes for a lot of places to change as well.

So back to the question:

Can I just set this variable as global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pass the variable to the form from your controller.

```
// Controller action
public function formAction()
{
    $lang = $this->getParam('lang');
    $form = new My_Form_Xyz($lang);
    $this->view->form = $form;
}

// My_Form_Xyz

protected $lang;

public function __construct($lang)
{
    $this->lang = $lang;
    parent::__construct();
}

public function init()
{
    switch ($this->lang) {
        case 'en':
            $selectOptions = array();
            break;
        case 'klingon':
            $selectOptions = array();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Injecting via form setter (as suggested by ArneRie) is better solution. But in case you don't have a discrete form class, or you generate the form from ini file, you can access the parameter like this anywhere after `$front->dispatch()` in your bootstrap

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParam('lang');
```